# modify object key value pair after for each

Tags: reactjs, object, state, key-value

I'm trying to set a count for the number of same cards in a deck. Every time I add a card, I would like to check to see if the same card exists inside my array of cards. If that card already exists i'd like to increase the count of a previous card by 1

My main issue is that when I try to render the decklist I'm not seeing the card count appear at all. I'm not sure if it's my function or my mapping?

```
state={
          cardCount: 0,
          currentDeck: [
            {
              name: 'card1',
              count: 0
            },
            {
              name: 'card2',
              count: 0
            },
            {
              name: 'card3',
              count: 0
            }
          ],
  }


//function to check for duplicate cards

 // if the card is already in the deck we add +1 to the count of that card
  addToDeck = (selection) =>{
    let card = {
      name: selection,
      count: (count)=>{ for(var x in this.state.currentDeck){ 
        if(x.name === selection){ 
          count = x.count+=1
        }
        else{
          count = 0
        }
      }  
     }
    }
    this.setState({currentDeck:[...this.state.currentDeck, card]})
  }


//div where I render the decklist

<div className="currentD">
              <h4>Deck List</h4>
                  <ul>
                  {currentDeck.map((card, index, num) => (
                <li className = 'cardinDeckList' key={index}>
                  <strong>{card.name}</strong><span key={num}>x{card.count}</span>
                </li>
              ))}
                  </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: React's state change detection doesn't work on nested objects, you will need to modify something at the top level

Comment: I believe others have addressed your question, but I'm here to ask if you've considered other data structures that lend themselves to quicker accesses. I suggest switching your `currentDeck` shape to be`{ [name]: count }`, instead of an array, to allow O(1) look up. Your check if a card exists is then as simple as `currentDeck[cardName]`. If this interests you then I can add as an answer working with an object versus array to update your state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are updating state is not valid. Your state will have object with name as selection and count as function, react doesn't call function inside your nested object.

You can use map method to update count if there is no update you can add new value in array.

```
addToDeck = (selection) =>{
  let isUpdated = false;

  const updatedDeck = this.state.currentDeck.map(c => {
    if (c.name === selection) {
      isUpdated = true;
      return {...c, count: c.count + 1 };
    }
    return c;
  });
  if(!isUpdated) {
    updatedDeck.push({ name: selection, count: 0 });
  }
  this.setState({currentDeck: updatedDeck })
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation this is pretty intuitive to me :)